# Provide command-line arguments for function in file

Tags: python

For example I have function that takes `--config` argument from command line.
So to launch it from console I have to enter following:

```
>>> my_function --config
```

I want to create file like `new_func.py` and launch `my_function --config` from here.

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you have a more specific example?
Otherwise it sounds like you need to import sys and then store the argument in a variable using sys.argv. An example would be nice :)

Answer (score 0):

Use argparse module:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Command line exemple.')
parser.add_argument('--config', dest='fileconf', action='store',
                   help='my argument description)')

args = parser.parse_args()
print args.fileconf # do something with fileconf value
```

[image]